# Openfiler AD integration and controlled access

Tags: active-directory, authentication, samba, openfiler

I integrated Openfiler with an Active Directory.

I configured a SMB/CIFS share as *`Controlled Access`* and set *`domain admins = PG`* and *`domain users = RO`*. This should give domain users readonly access to the share.

When I open a share from a Vista machine on the domain everything works.

When I try to open the share from a Vista machine that is *not* on the domain I get the login prompt as expected, but no matter what I enter, I get a message

`\192.168.1.51\raided.main.iso is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.`

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

When I configure the share as *`Public guest access`* it works both ways. Both of these machines are on the same network.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, though understanding is still lacking.

It turns out that if you access the SMB share through the NETBIOS name entered in Openfiler's `SMB / CIFS Setup` screen, Vista is happy.

Doing the same using the IP address does not work.

Most perplexingly, I have a Windows Server 2003 machine (not on the domain) that behaves the other way around, i.e. access is only allowed through the IP address and *not* through the NETBIOS name.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience (also mixed environment of Vistas Business and Basic connecting to OpenFiler 2.3) - when the username and password of a user logged in to the Windows not connected to Active Directory is the same as the user included in Active Directory it simply works.

So just create the user in Active Directory, log in to "that" user to the computer not connected to AD and it will just work.

Warning: it sometimes takes time for OpenFiler to read new users and groups from AD. When you add the user to AD first check in OpenFiler's panel if it is synchronized.

Comment: That's a good idea but for the fact that I integrated with AD for the easy maintenance. I can just as well maintain the roaming users in the local Openfiler LDAP server.

Comment: How many computers not connected to domain do you have? In my case it's minority of them, so it's ok to manage their logins and passwords by hand in AD. Also managing users and groups in Active Directory is simply more comfortable and powerful.

Comment: We're doing R&D on a domain completely isolated and secured from the company domain. Project members have their computers added to the company domain yet needs to access our private domain with separate credentials.